# Which games in my library are supported by steam?

Tags: steam, linux

I want to see a list of the games in my library, which are support under linux.

How can I see this list? Currently, I use windows.

Comment: I know you can view the store page for each game in your library and it will tell you what platforms its compatible on there. I don't think there's really any other way.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn there was a "Linux" and "Mac" filter before. I guess it was either removed or it never existed in the first place. ¯\＿(ツ)＿/¯

Answer (score 10):

The Linux version of Steam has a specific library for Steam OS + Linux.

[image: STEAM OS + LINUX (347)]

On other platforms you can use [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/linux/): sign in via Steam and show owned games only.

[image: SteamOS & Linux Products on Steam. Show owned games]

Comment: So basically, all you have to do is link your steam library from your Windows device and it'll sort it out?

Comment: @TimmyJim your Steam library is linked to your account, not your device.

Comment: This steamdb page does not exist. It seems there is no way to to do this without being on linux.